# Title label errors in infowindow in CartoDB - help?

Tags: carto, infowindow

Sometimes, for no discernible reason, the title labels in my CartoDB infowindows start malfunctioning. They show the underscore in the title label, and I am not able to click on the "Change title labels" button (the A with the pencil). Any idea of what could be going on with this and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured out what was going on, so I figured I should share in case anyone else has this problem. The issue was that I had "text" in some of my column titles, and this was messing up the system. A similar thing happened when I had "title" as one of my column titles.